# How do I find the correct probabilities for the bust-out rates for an average player in blackjack?

Tags: c++, probability, blackjack

I would like to be able to find the bust-out rate for an average player in blackjack. The correct values can be found on the following website: http://www.blackjackage.com/bust-out-rate.php

To achieve this, I implemented a card and a deck class which is responsible for dealing the cards and shuffling. In the main file, cards.cpp, I made a separate function called probabilities() with parameters threshold and iterations. The threshold will be going from 10 to 20, which will determine what total the player must achieve before busting. The iterations will determine how many times I would like to repeat this to find how often the player busts before reaching the threshold.
Here are my probabilities per threshold:
10: 0.6577
11: 0.849
12: 0.8942
13: 0.8955
14: 0.8777
15: 0.8531
16: 0.8714
17: 0.872
18: 0.8799
19: 0.8443
20: 0.8011
Compared to the values found on the website, they are very off. Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong in my probabilities function?

**Main File:**

```
#include "deck.h"
using namespace std;

int chooseRand(int a, int b){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r = rand()%2;
    if(r==0) return a;
    else return b;
}

int probabilities(int threshold, int iterations){
    Deck deck;
    deck.shuffle();
    Card currentCard;
    int cardVal = 0;
    int cardSum = 0;
    int bust = 0;
    int stand = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<iterations; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<iterations && cardSum<threshold; j++){
            currentCard = deck.dealCard(); //
            cardVal = currentCard.getVal();
            if(deck.remainingCards() < 1) deck.shuffle();
            if(cardSum < threshold){
                if(cardVal != 1 && cardVal != 11 && cardVal != 12 && cardVal != 13) cardSum += cardVal;
                else if(cardVal == 1) cardSum += chooseRand(1,11);
                else if((cardVal == 11 || cardVal == 12 || cardVal == 13) && cardSum < threshold) cardSum += 10;
                }   
            else break;
        }
        if(cardSum > threshold)bust++; cardSum = 0;
    }
    return (float)(bust);
}

int main(){
    Deck deck;
    Card currentCard;
    int iterations = 10000;
    for(int i = 10; i<=20; i++){
        cout<<i<<": "<<(float)(probabilities(i, iterations)/10000.0)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**deck.h**

```
#ifndef DECK_H
#define DECK_H
#include "card.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int NUM_CARDS_DECK = 52;

class Deck
{ 
public:
      Deck();
      Card dealCard();
      void shuffle();
      void printDeck() const;
      int remainingCards();
private:
    Card *deck; //Create a dynamically allocated array of cards
    int currentCard;
    int remainCardCount;

};

Deck::Deck(){
    string faces[] = {"Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
                        "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    string suits[] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
*/

    int faces[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
    int suits[] = {1, 2, 3};
    deck = new Card[NUM_CARDS_DECK];
    currentCard = 0;
    //Now fill up the card array with values
    for(int i = 0; i<NUM_CARDS_DECK; i++){
        deck[i] = Card(faces[i%13], suits[i/13]);
    }

}

void Deck:: printDeck() const{
    cout<<left;
    for(int i = 0; i<NUM_CARDS_DECK; i++){
        cout<<setw(19)<<deck[i].print();
        if((i+1)%4 == 0){
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
}

void Deck::shuffle(){
    currentCard = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<NUM_CARDS_DECK; i++){
        int j = (rand() + time(0)) % NUM_CARDS_DECK;
        Card temp = deck[i];
        deck[i] = deck[j];
        deck[j] = temp;
    }
}

int Deck::remainingCards(){
    return remainCardCount;
}

Card Deck::dealCard(){
    remainCardCount = 52;
    if(currentCard > NUM_CARDS_DECK){
        shuffle();
        remainCardCount = 0;
    }
    if(currentCard < NUM_CARDS_DECK){
        remainCardCount = 51-currentCard;
        return (deck[currentCard++]);
    }
    return(deck[0]);
}

#endif
```

**card.h**

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Card{
public:
    Card(int cardNum, int cardSuit);
    int getVal();//For blackjack
    string print() const;
    Card();
private:
    int num;
    int suit;
};

Card::Card(){}
Card::Card(int cardNum, int cardSuit){
    num = cardNum;
    suit = cardSuit;
}

int Card::getVal(){
    return num;
}

string Card::print() const{
    return (to_string(num) + "of" + to_string(suit));
}

#endif
```

Comment: You should call `srand` only once. It's usually done as one of the first things in `main`.

Comment: It is you shuffle method.   The j value is not right.  j should vary from 0 to 51 just like I

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free debugging service, and you should show your attempts at debugging the code with a debugger or other simpler methods such as debug print statements. You can also test each part of the code separately to figure out exactly which part of the code is causing the problem, and make a [mcve]. This won't be the only time you end up with a bug in your code, and learning to debug your programs will help you much more than having someone find the bug for you. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/